# Possiblity to find an object based on id then render it inside a react component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to find an object based on its `id` then render it in a component.

```
getInitialState() {
  return { item: [] }
 },

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({item: this.props.items.filter(item => (item.id == this.props.match.params.id))})
}
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.item) // result is empty array
}
```

If I do not want to use `setState` and find object in `render` method then I will get:

```
render() {
  var item = this.props.items.find(item => (item.id == this.props.match.params.id))
  console.log(item) // First it is undefined then it will be found
  var title = item.title
  return (
    <div>
      {title}
    </div>
```

How can I find object based on the `params.id` then render it inside the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
  var item = this.props.items.find(item => (item.id == this.props.match.params.id))


  //This is what you should do to show that it's loading.
  if(!item || !item.id){
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }


  console.log(item) // First it is undefined then it will be found
  var title = item.title
  return (
    <div>
      {title}
    </div>
```